# SwiftUI `view` should be removed from the super view stack after some time

Tags: swiftui

I would like to implement a toast view in SwiftUI, I am able to do that, but after some time I want to remove the view from the stack. How can we remove current view from the stack?

Here is my code.

```swift
// Actual View 
struct FormView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .toast() // here is the toast message presentation
    }
}

// Toast View 
struct ToastMessage<Content: View>: View {
    @State var present: Bool = false
    let contentView: Content
    
    init( contentView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.contentView = contentView()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            contentView
            if present {
                HStack {
                    Text(" You're logged in. !!")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.65))
                .cornerRadius(32)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,  alignment: .center)
                .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y + 80)
                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 2))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation {
                present = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                    present = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func toast() ->  some View {
        ToastMessage(contentView: {self})
    }
}
```

[image]
Even after 5 seconds, still, this toast view is present in the `View's` stack. I'm expecting the `ToastMessage` view should be removed from the `FormView` after 5 seconds.
Your help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, `ToastMessage` is still in the hierarchy because `toast()` returns `ToastMessage` no matter what. Then, *within* toast message, there's a conditional about whether or not the actual message is displayed.

If you don't want `ToastMessage` in the hierarchy at all, you'd need to move the `@State` on level up so that you can use a conditional to determine whether or not it gets displayed.

```
// Actual View
struct FormView: View {
    @State private var showToast = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .toast(show: $showToast)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation { showToast = true }
            }
    }
}

// Toast View
struct ToastMessage<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var present: Bool
    let contentView: Content
    
    init(present: Binding<Bool>, contentView: @escaping () -> Content) {
        _present = present
        self.contentView = contentView()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            contentView
            HStack {
                Text(" You're logged in. !!")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.65))
            .cornerRadius(32)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,  alignment: .center)
            .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y + 80)
            .transition(.move(edge: .top))
            .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 1, blendDuration: 2))
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                withAnimation {
                    present = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func toast(show: Binding<Bool>) ->  some View {
        if show.wrappedValue {
            ToastMessage(present: show,contentView: {self})
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, if you *don't* want to move the state up, there's not necessarily any harm in keeping `ToastMessage` in the hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for the solution,  yeah I'm aware of it but I'm thinking how SwiftUI missed/ should have something like `removeFromSuperView()` without handling from its `superview`.

Comment: Maybe, but to what end? Views that don’t really have an effect get optimized out, as far as I know. You could change your structure so even the ZStack doesn’t get included if present isn’t true.